# Expo BarCodeScanner if the user denies camera permission program is unable to ask again

Tags: react-native, permissions, expo, barcode-scanner

When using Expo BarCodeScanner once the user denies required camera permission following `requestPermissionsAsync()` calls will always return `'denied'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the expo [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/#:%7E:text=Often%20you%20want,launch%20the%20project.);

> Often you want to be able to test what happens when a user rejects a permission, to ensure that it has the desired behavior. An operating-system level restriction on both iOS and Android prohibits an app from asking for the same permission more than once (you can imagine how this could be annoying for the user to be repeatedly prompted for permissions). So in order to test different flows involving permissions in development, you may need to uninstall and reinstall the Expo Go app. In the simulator this is as easy as deleting the app, and expo-cli will automatically install it again next time you launch the project.

But, you don't always need to remove the application and install it again. You can also give the permissions manually by going into settings and application permissions.

Comment: A third option would be using React Native's [`Linking` library](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/). When `Linking.openURL('app-settings:')` (on iOS) is executed the settings page for the Expo Go application will be opened then you can allow required permissions.